# Can I use a blob defined field to store more than 255 Text characters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes

As the title states, i´m not sure whether I should/can use a blob field to store text. I need to increase the amount of text in a field to over 255. Is the blob the way to go?

Comment: What data format are you using?  If string is limited, it probably doesn't support BLOB.

Comment: The original field was defined as text 255 with characters

Comment: What data format?  I'm not aware of any modern non-shapefile data source that doesn't support at least 4000.

Comment: I thought when I define a field in arcgis as Text I can choose how many characters the field can contain up to 255. I must be very mistaken

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, other?

Comment: Shapefiles limit you to 254, but I just created file geodatabase fields "foo text(8000)" and "bar text(16000)"; in fact, the FGDB text storage limit is 2^31-1.  I usually define my tables from SQL (in RDBMSes), so a rarely see that UI.  I'm not quite sure how to leave it completely unbounded (except on conversion from an enterprise table).

Comment: OK...I think my confusion stems from the fact that I had read literature regarding Shapes.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, BLOB is *not* the way to go when arbitrary text is desired -- Assuming the contents of a BLOB column is ASCII can become a security issue!  Instead, you should be looking at CLOB (UTF-8) or NCLOB (UTF-16) data types (if supported).  The fallback (for formats that don't support LOB types) is concatenation of string fields,
or ancillary files with data, and the name of the file in the string field.